# "Not working" is becoming all too common

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

There are far too many questions that incorporate "not working". Can we check for "not working" in the body during the question asking process at Stack Overflow and request that the user elaborate if necessary. I'm not saying prevent the question from being posted or validate it in anyway, just help the user out in how to ask the question the right way. We can't really check for questions that show no demonstration of attempt by the OP, but we can check for "not working" or "doesn't work".

Note: I *know* there are exceptions (i.e. "not working as I'd expect because..."), which is why I say a hint only.

Comment: People who don't understand why "not working" isn't helpful are going to need more than a warning to get them to understand how to ask a good question. They would still end up leaving out useful information until prompted specifically by a commenter.

Answer (score 7):

We already have a off-topic reason for those posts lacking in enough detail to debug the issue.

I foresee too many false positives on posts that use the wording but include a minimal sample and error message.

There is no recent uptick in 'not working' being used; people have been posting overly vague problem descriptions since the dawn of this site. The problem is that people that post that kind of description also *don't read warnings*. Or the help center. Or any other hints and help offered along the way when posting.

Comment: Fair enough....